# PostgreSQL 'BEFORE INSERT' TRIGGER Problem with QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, trigger

In PostgreSQL I created a simple PL/pgSQL trigger function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_rv_default_farben() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parent_rv IS NULL THEN
        IF NEW.anz_rohre = 12 THEN
            NEW.farben := '{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}';
        ELSIF NEW.anz_rohre = 24 THEN
            NEW.farben :='{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24}';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER rv_farben_def_trig BEFORE INSERT ON rohrverbund EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_rv_default_farben();
```

In QGIS, when I add a feature to layer `rohrverbund` with attribute `parent_rv` left `NULL` as well as `anz_rohre` set to `12` and try to save edits for this layer I get an error message like (partial in german, but I try to translate ...)

```
Could not commit changes to layer rohrverbund

Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.

  Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: FEHLER:  Record »new« hat noch keinen Wert [... has no value]
    DETAIL:  Die Tupelstruktur eines Records ohne Wert ist unbestimmt. [tuple structure of a record with no value is undetermined]
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL-Funktion set_rv_default_farben() Zeile 3 bei IF [line 3 at IF]
```

What am I missing? The recommendation and all examples I found use `BEFORE INSERT` and `NEW.attribute`, better use `AFTER INSERT` and `OLD.attribute`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues. First, the one that produce the error, the trigger must specify that you are applying it `for each row`. Secondly, the function must `return New` otherwise nothing will be inserted in the DB.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_rv_default_farben() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parent_rv IS NULL THEN
        IF NEW.anz_rohre = 12 THEN
            NEW.farben := '{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}';
        ELSIF NEW.anz_rohre = 24 THEN
            NEW.farben :='{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24}';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;


CREATE TRIGGER rv_farben_def_trig 
BEFORE INSERT ON rohrverbund 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_rv_default_farben();
```